# Refresh DataGridView after executing SQL Command?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Here is my code:

```
 cn.Open()
     cmd.CommandText = "insert into Student values('" ......
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
```

After closing the connection I want my DataGridView to refresh it's data's also.
I am new in VB.NET I tried `datagridview.refresh()` but it's not working as I think it's like repainting not updating it's data's.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update the underlying business object, the UI should update automatically. My guess it that you forgot to do data binding, for example `DataGridView.DataSource = yourDataTable`.

**EDIT:** the easiest way from where you are right now would probably be to replace this:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb.aspx):

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

and then:

```
DataGridView.DataSource = dt
```

If you need database updates, you may want to use a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879f39d8.aspx) and its [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx) method. The overload I linked is specifically for a DataTable, i.e. you don't need a DataSet, unless you have it already.

Comment: Yes, I didn't use any data bindings, how can I do so please ?

Comment: Thank you Neolisk the problem solved, that was very kind of you :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Neolisk said you have to do databinding .. for example

```
Dim ds as DataSet
Dim sSql As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

sSql = cnEZApp.CreateCommand()

cmd = New Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM student ORDER by kode", conn)
cmd.Fill(ds, "student")
dgvGuru.DataSource = ds.Tables("student")
```

So, to update table as datasource you have to do

```
sSql.CommandText = "insert into Student(...) values(...)"
cmd.UpdateCommand = sSql
cmd.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you matzone  appreciated :)